# How to add username in url before controller/action in yii2

Tags: url-rewriting, url-routing, yii2-advanced-app, yii-components

I'm working on a site and I need to customize site URL in such a manner that it will work like `<username>/<controller>/<action>` after login the user.

I have tried it with followings rules in Yii 2.0 configuration file:-

```
'rules' => [                
                '<username>/<controller:(site|comment)>/<id:\d+>/<action:(index|home|update|delete)>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ],
```

But it shows me #404 error. Any Helps?

Comment: I have found the solution:-

 'rules' => [
  
                '<username>/<controller:(site|pages)>/<action:(index|home|delete)>' => '<controller>/<action>',
   ],